# how to store images and text in same field in a mysql database?

Tags: php, sql, database, image

I need to store both text and images to be stored in the same field?
How can this be implemented in php using a mysql database?
I have used BLOB to store images in the past .
Which datatype should I use for this problem?

And how will this work...?

Comment: Don't do that. Better store them seperately.

Comment: it is denormalize your database... so please avoid this thing and make it separated

Comment: The obvious question is "why?"

Comment: Actually I am implementing a small questionnaire for my site. So the questions have options which will be sometimes a combination of text and images.Note:there can be multiple images for 1 option and at any position :ie in the beginning of the text ,in the middle of the text and at the end of the text.....How to implement this so that I am able to correctly display the option content with the text and images in the correct order..... –

Comment: @AjaxAristodemos It was a lot lower a couple of hours ago.  But it's sorted now.

Comment: @GordonM:why you got my account banned?....

Answer (score 5):

First thing to say, **DON'T DO THAT!**  Columns in a database are supposed to be atomic, which means they hold one and only one piece of information.  It's the cardinal rule of the First Normal Form.  If you try to cram more than one item of data into a column, you'll violate that rule and you WILL experience a world of hurt later on.

In theory, you could use whatever front end you're accessing the database with to serialize the data into a string and store that (in php, for example, you could do `$dataToStore = serialize (array 'Some string', $someData);`).  Then you'd use unserialize to extract the image data and the text back into separate items.

But why would you want to do that?  It's extra work that you don't need to do, in order to make your database design less optimal than it could be.  What's wrong with simply adding another column to the table you want to store the data in, one for the text and one for the image?

If you don't think your approach is a problem, then take it from someone who was hired to work on a database that was full of serialized data, it is.  It's an enormous problem.  It makes working with the database almost impossible.  You have to pull the data into the scripting language you're using and unserialize it before you can do anything with it.  You can't use SQL statements to query serialized data.

Comment: Actually I am implementing a small questionnaire for my site. So the questions have options which will be sometimes a combination of text and images.Note:there can be multiple images for 1 option and at any position :ie in the beginning of the text ,in the middle of the text and at the end of the text.....How to implement this so that I am able to correctly display the option content with the text and images in the correct order.....

Comment: If there can be multiple images then that means you have a one to many relationship.  You model those with a dependant table for the images, and use foreign keys to tie the images back to the row in the parent table they depend on.  You seriously need to rethink your database design.  It sounds like it's currently horribly wrong.

Comment: I am storing the options currently as text only.now i am adding the feature to have images in the options as well...How will I link images and text... How to know the order of the images and the text in the options .....?